# FullCalendar: Changing Event Background Color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

My issue is simple but frustrating. I'm using arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and polling the data from the db so the output is dynamic. The events created currently have only 1 background color. Not the cell but the event bar itself. I'm very new to javascript so creating any functions are driving me loopy. I have read, and re-read and am now banging my head because I am now stumped with this. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventBackgroundColor/ Any help is welcomed thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple pass the colour as a property:

```
events: [{title:'test', start: new Date(), color: 'red'}]
```

or

```
events: [{title:'test', start: new Date(), color: '#ff0000'}]
```